# How to append to wxPython ListCtlr within a button click

Tags: wxpython, listctrl

I'm hoping someone can help me.  I'm not sure where to look.  I'm creating a GUI application with wxPython.  I would simple window with a listctlr and a button.  When you click on the button I need to run a process.  This process has a loop that opens a browser with selenium, does some processing.  For each iteration I would like to append that result to the listctrl.  As of now the list does not update until the process is complete.  I would like it to update the list after each loop iteration. Can you please help or point me in the right direction?

```
    import sys
    import wx

    from collections import defaultdict
    from selenium import common
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select


    class MainWindow(wx.Frame):

        def __init__(self, parent, title):
            super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent, title=title)


            def process_applications(event):
                my_cursor = wx.Cursor(wx.CURSOR_WAIT)
                self.panel.SetCursor(my_cursor)
               
                for x, y in app.items():
                    index = self.list.InsertItem(sys.maxsize, student_application['FirstName'] + " " + student_application['LastName'])
                    
                    .... Process selenium and data....
                    
                    self.list.SetItem(index, 1, 'Success')
                    self.list.SetItem(index, 2, '12452134234')
                    self.list.SetItemBackgroundColour(index, wx.GREEN)
                    my_cursor = wx.Cursor(wx.CURSOR_DEFAULT)
                    self.panel.SetCursor(my_cursor)
               
            self.panel = wx.Panel(self)

            box = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

            icon = wx.Icon()
            icon.CopyFromBitmap(wx.Bitmap("icon.ico", wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY))
            self.SetIcon(icon)

            self.button = wx.Button(self.panel, wx.ID_ANY, 'Process Applications', size=(200, 50))
            self.button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, process_applications)
            self.list = wx.ListCtrl(self.panel, -1, style=wx.LC_REPORT)
            self.list.InsertColumn(0, "Student's Name", width=150)
            self.list.InsertColumn(1, 'Status', wx.LIST_FORMAT_CENTER, 100)
            self.list.InsertColumn(2, 'Confirmation #', wx.LIST_FORMAT_RIGHT, 100)
            box.Add(self.list, 1, wx.EXPAND)
            box.AddSpacer(5)
            box.Add(self.button, 1, wx.CENTER)
            box.AddSpacer(5)
            self.panel.SetSizer(box)
            self.panel.Fit()
            self.Centre()
            self.Show(True)

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        ex = wx.App()
        MainWindow(None, 'NCCCO Application Process')
        ex.MainLoop()
```

Comment: I suspect that a `Refresh` or `Update` will do the job, issued after each iteration.

Comment: I've tried adding the list.RefreshItems(itemFrom, itemTo) but got the same results of not refreshing the list until the loop is completed

Comment: I was referring to a self.Update() i.e. the frame. I'd replace the cursor stuff in the loop with that and put the cursor updates after the loop. You will probably need to use `wx.Yield` as well to yield control momentarily back to the main loop, as you're in what could be a slow loop.

Comment: Thank you Rolf!  Adding self.Update and a wx.Yield with in the loop worked!

Comment: My pleasure....